# E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19) How do I avoid this error? Do I need to release the Media Player?

Tags: java, android, debugging, error-handling, android-mediaplayer

So in the onClick() method a media file is generated and played. Click again, the random number generator generates another media file, regardless of whether the last one is finished playing. If tapped to fast, they will overlap. But that's not my concern at the moment. How do I avoid this error?

```
mp3.release();
mp3.stop();
```

mp3 = null;

^^ Not sure if that's the right order but this also gives me another error and I'm not sure where to place it.

```
onCompletion(){}
```

Might work. Anyone have any suggestions?

package com.example.okunato.chance;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.Random;

import pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer introSong;
    MediaPlayer introVoice;
    MediaPlayer mp3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        introSong = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.theme); // Backround music
        introVoice = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.intro); // the intro that plays upon open

        final int mediaLengthSong = introSong.getCurrentPosition();
        final int mediaLengthVoice = introVoice.getCurrentPosition();

        final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                String number = incomingNumber;
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    introVoice.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                    introSong.seekTo(mediaLengthSong);

                    introSong.pause();
                    introVoice.pause();
                }
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    introVoice.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                    introSong.seekTo(mediaLengthSong);

                    introSong.pause();
                    introVoice.pause();
                }
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {

                    final int MAX_VOLUME = 100;
                    int soundVolume = 65;

                    final float volume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(MAX_VOLUME - soundVolume) / Math.log(MAX_VOLUME)));
                    introSong.setVolume(volume, volume);
                    introSong.seekTo(mediaLengthSong);
                    introSong.start(); // it doesn't loop

                    new CountDownTimer(2000, 100) {
                        public void onFinish() {
                            // When timer is finished
                            // Execute your code here
                            introVoice.start();
                        }

                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            // millisUntilFinished    The amount of time until finished.
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            }
        };
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        // all this is to pause when the user has a phone call or closes the app*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        introSong.pause();
        introVoice.pause();
        mp3.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        introSong.pause();
        introVoice.pause();
        mp3.pause();
    }

   @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        playMediaPlayer();
    }

    private void playMediaPlayer() {
        introSong.start();
        introVoice.start();
    }

    // Not really sure what I did this for but it seems to help pause and play

    int count = 0;

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(introVoice.isPlaying() == true){
            introVoice.stop();
        }

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
        final GifImageView home = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gif);

        count++;

        for (int x = 0; x <= 1; x++){
            mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.highlyfavorable);
            final int mediaLengthVoice = mp3.getCurrentPosition();

            final GifImageView vuImg = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gif);

            final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                    String number = incomingNumber;
                    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                        mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                        mp3.pause();
                    }
                    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                        mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                        mp3.pause();
                    }
                    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        vuImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);

                        mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                        mp3.start();

                        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
                        v.vibrate(3500);
                    }
                }
            };
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

            new CountDownTimer(5000, 100) {
                public void onFinish() {
                    home.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
                }

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    // millisUntilFinished    The amount of time until finished.
                }
            }.start();

        }


        if (count % 2 != 0 && count > 1) {

            if (random == 1) {
                mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.veryunfavorable);
                final int mediaLengthVoice = mp3.getCurrentPosition();

                final GifImageView vuImg = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gif);

                final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                        String number = incomingNumber;
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.pause();
                        }
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.pause();
                        }
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                            vuImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);

                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.start();

                            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
                            v.vibrate(500);
                        }
                    }
                };
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

            }

            else if (random == 2) {
                mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.unfavorable);
                final int mediaLengthVoice = mp3.getCurrentPosition();

                final GifImageView vuImg = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gif);

                final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                        String number = incomingNumber;
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.pause();
                        }
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.pause();
                        }
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                            vuImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);

                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.start();

                            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
                            v.vibrate(1000);
                        }
                    }
                };
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


            }

            else if (random == 3) {
                mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fair);
                final int mediaLengthVoice = mp3.getCurrentPosition();

                final GifImageView vuImg = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gif);

                final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                        String number = incomingNumber;
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.pause();
                        }
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.pause();
                        }
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                            vuImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);

                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.start();

                            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
                            v.vibrate(1500);
                        }
                    }
                };
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            }

            else if (random == 4) {
                mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.veryfavorable);
                final int mediaLengthVoice = mp3.getCurrentPosition();

                final GifImageView vuImg = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gif);

                final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                        String number = incomingNumber;
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.pause();
                        }
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.pause();
                        }
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                            vuImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);

                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.start();

                            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
                            v.vibrate(2500);
                        }
                    }
                };
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


            }

            else if (random == 5) {
                mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.highlyfavorable);
                final int mediaLengthVoice = mp3.getCurrentPosition();

                final GifImageView vuImg = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gif);

                final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                        String number = incomingNumber;
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.pause();
                        }
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.pause();
                        }
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                            vuImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);

                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.start();

                            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
                            v.vibrate(3000);
                        }
                    }
                };
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


            }

            else if (random == 6) {
                mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.highlyunfavorable);
                final int mediaLengthVoice = mp3.getCurrentPosition();

                final GifImageView vuImg = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gif);

                final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                        String number = incomingNumber;
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.pause();
                        }
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.pause();
                        }
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                            vuImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);

                            mp3.seekTo(mediaLengthVoice);
                            mp3.start();
                        }
                    }
                };
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


            }

            else {
                int[] quote = new int[]{R.raw.q1, R.raw.q2, R.raw.q3, R.raw.q4, R.raw.q5, R.raw.q6, R.raw.q7, R.raw.q8,
                        R.raw.q9, R.raw.q10, R.raw.q11, R.raw.q12, R.raw.q13, R.raw.q14, R.raw.q15, R.raw.q16,
                        R.raw.q17, R.raw.q18, R.raw.q19, R.raw.q20, R.raw.q21, R.raw.q22, R.raw.q23, R.raw.q24, R.raw.q25};


                int random2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(25);
                // Random number generator for the Quotes above
                final MediaPlayer quotes;


                quotes = MediaPlayer.create(this, quote[random2]);
                final GifImageView quotesImg = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gif);

                final int mediaLengthResponse = quotes.getCurrentPosition();

                final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                        String number = incomingNumber;
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                            quotes.seekTo(mediaLengthResponse);
                            quotes.pause();
                        }
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                            quotes.seekTo(mediaLengthResponse);
                            quotes.pause();
                        }
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                            quotesImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);

                            quotes.seekTo(mediaLengthResponse);
                            quotes.start();
                        }
                    }
                };
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            }
        }

        /*@Override
        protected void onCompletion (MediaPlayer mp3) {
            super.onCompletion();
            mp3.release();

        }*/
    }
}
```

May whoever sees this code, be inspired.

Comment: Can you provide the entire code... I was facing same error when I was trying to play a streaming audio. The order should be `stop()` and then `release()` but that depends on the parameters that you defined when you create the MediaPlayer Object.

Comment: It's there. Take a look.

Comment: hey, if you like what you see, just press that up arrow.

Comment: @AndroidStorm Thoughts?